# Querying whole OBJECT or Document using LIKE condition in CrateDB

Tags: cratedb

I have a table with one of the field defined as `"attributes" OBJECT (DYNAMIC)`.

Now, my usecase is to be able to check if any particular string is part of this OBJECT. In SQL terms I want to execute a `like` command on this whole OBJECT or even whole Document. Do we currently support this feature

Query I want to execute: `select * from gra.test_table where attributes like '%53.22.232.27%';`

When I execute this on Crate 4.5.1, I am running into error: `UnsupportedFeatureException[Unknown function: (gra.test_table.attributes LIKE '%53.22.232.27%'), no overload found for matching argument types: (object, text). Possible candidates: op_like(text, text):boolean]`

When I execute this on Crate 3.x, I am running into error:
`SQLActionException[SQLParseException: Cannot cast attributes to type string]`

Table structure is below and `attributes` is the field I am talking about

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "test"."test_table" (
   "accountname" STRING,
   "attributes" OBJECT (DYNAMIC) AS (
      "accesslist" STRING,
      "accesslistid" STRING,
      "accessmask" STRING,
      "accessreason" STRING
   ),
   "employeeid" STRING,
   "day" TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY ("day", "id"),
   INDEX "all_columns_ft" USING FULLTEXT ("employeeid") WITH (
      analyzer = 'standard'
   )
)
CLUSTERED INTO 1 SHARDS
PARTITIONED BY ("day")
WITH (
   "allocation.max_retries" = 5
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `like` on a whole object is not supported.
A possible (slow) workaround could be to use a [regular expression operator](https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/4.6/general/dql/selects.html#sql-dql-regexp) on the `text` cast of an `object` typed column:

`select * from gra.test_table where attributes::text ~ '.*53.22.232.27.*'`

But be aware that through the `cast`, no index could be utilized and such a full table scan + filter is executed resulting in slow query execution.